# pandas: 0.19.2 read_excel is unable to recognize encoding properly even after giving encoding= 'UTF - 8'

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, thread-exceptions

```
converterS = {col: str for col in x}
excel_df = pd.read_excel(xlsx_file,encoding = 'utf-8', sheetname=table,converters= converterS)
```

error : 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa2' in position 25: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: did you try without `utf-8`?

Comment: Yeah even the same issue @ghanem

Comment: BTW, `read_excel` doesn't support `encoding` variable, are you sure that you are running the right code?

Comment: it is not throwing any syntax issue with encoding parmeter..Was trying to figure out why this given encoding is not considering